# vite/rollup: how to load js chunks from same directory as index.html or by relative paths?

Tags: vite, rollup

I need my index.html to load the js src file relatively:
to achieve this I added this to my viteConfig

`entryFileNames: '[name]-[hash].js'`

This results in this import in the index.html:

`<script type="module" crossorigin src="/index-f727dfb8.js"></script>`

As the files get served in a static folder this would mean the path is incorrect in dev + prod as they are nested in the static folder `public/export/index.html`

This would solve the problem
`<script type="module" crossorigin src="index-f727dfb8.js"></script>`

How can I remove the leading slash

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer:

in vite config set `base: ''`
the default is  `base: '/'`